# Adding some images with PHPMailer

Tags: php, image, phpmailer

I am using phpmailer to send an email. The email is a template with a bunch of images. So I use the AddEmbeddedImage() method to add images. The problem is that I want to add a lots of images, how could I specify the path parameter in order to load all the images in one time ? Does AddEmbeddedImage('images/*.jpg',...) makes sense ?

For information, I instantiate `$mailer = new PHPMailer();` then I use `$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('img/some_image.jpg', 'image');` but I can't do that twenty times for twenty images

Comment: What is your current code?

Comment: Click "edit" below your question to update its content, it will be easier to read for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over all images in a folder and add that with a foreach loop. For example:

```
<?php
function get_files ($dir, $_ext = 'jpg') {
    $files = array();
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;
                $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                
                if ($ext == $_ext) {
                    $files[] = $file;
                }
            }
            closedir($dh);
        }
    }
    return $files;
}

/**
* You can change the second parameter so you can get other image types 
* (png, gif, etc.)
*/
$images = get_files ("/path/to/folder/of/images/");
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $mail->AddEmbeddedImage ($image, 'image');
}
?>
```

Directory code taken from [PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php).

Comment: Great ! I although thought it could be done simply by some specific PHPmailer method

Comment: It really isn't PHPMailer's job to handle directory parsing and adding multiple files when you can do it yourself. It just adds unnecessary complexity IMO.